# Struts 1.3 action forward parameter

Tags: java, struts-1, forwarding

I'm working on a little project which uses Struts 1.3 and I encountered the following problem.

After some business logic takes place in an `Action` i want to forward the control to another Action which is mapped in `struts-config.xml`.

Usually this is the way I'm solving this:

**struts-config.xml**

```
<action path="/boardCreate" type="com.example.BoardCreateAction" name="BoardCreateForm" input="/board.jsp">
    <forward name="success" path="/board.do" redirect="true" />
</action>
```

**Java action class**

```
return mapping.findForward("success");
```

This will take make a redirect to the `board.do` action which is also mapped there.

My problem is that I want to redirect the control to something like:

```
<forward name="success" path="/board.do?id=1" redirect="true" />
```

Notice the **id=1** parameter. Is this any other way except rebuilding my own action forward for this? I can't find any documentation debating this matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
ActionRedirect redirect = new ActionRedirect(mapping.findForward("success"));
redirect.addParameter("id", theId);
return redirect;
```

See http://tool.oschina.net/uploads/apidocs/struts-1.3.10/org/apache/struts/action/ActionRedirect.html